# why does my java code go into an infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops

My code below seems to go into an infinite loop and I'm puzzled as to why.  I introduced pieces of code until I triggered the error message:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
        boolean notDone = true;
        while (notDone)//go into loop automatically
        {
            if(!in.hasNextDouble()){
                if(count==0){//this part generates bugs
                    System.out.print("Error: No input");
                }else{
                    notDone = false;
                }

            }else{
                sum+= in.nextDouble();
                count++;
                System.out.print("Enter a value, Q to quit: ");
            }
        }
        double average = sum / count;
        System.out.printf("Average: %.2f\n", average);
        return;
    }
}
```

As noted in the comment, the main culprit is these lines:

```
                if(count==0){ //this part generates bugs
                    System.out.print("Error: No input");
                }
```

The purpose of this if case is so that the user stays in the loop and is reminded that valid input is needed until it receives valid input, but it's not like there isn't a way to break out of the loop, because the user can break out of the loop on condition that the program receives valid input(at least one double value, followed by a non-double value).

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Your code goes into an infinite loop because the conditional does not make any progress in case no `double` is detected. When this happens, you print a message, but you do not remove junk input from the scanner.

Adding `in.nextLine()` to the conditional will fix this problem:

```
if(!in.hasNextDouble()){
    if (!in.hasNextLine()) {
        // The input is closed - exit the program.
        System.out.print("Input is closed. Exiting.");
        return;
    }
    in.nextLine();
    ... // The rest of your code
} ...
```